# JQM fixed footer "floating"

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

In JQM I want to have a fixed footer but at the same time have a max width of the page (contents to the left). It works fine until I add data-position="fixed" (fixed footer). The footer now fills the whole window and not just 480px. Is this OK or is it a bug? Any ideas how to solve the problem?

```
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a"  data-position="fixed"><h1> </h1>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
if ($(window).width() > 480) {
    $('#page1, #gubbo').css('width', '480px' );
}         
});

$(window).resize(function() {
if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
    $('#page1, #gubbo').css('width', '' );
} else {
    $('#page1, #gubbo').css('width', '480px' );
}
});
```

Comment: what element got the "gubbo" id?

Comment: gubbo is one page of a multi-page. Page1 is another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted to jQuery Forum and the answer was that a fixed footer is not considered to be part of the page even if it is still "within" data-role="page". So the solution should be to add e.g. an id to each footer and add that id to the JS above